# Location Meta-Data for open Graph object

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

My site contains profile pages for companies.

I have recently converted the open graph metadata from a 'website' default object to a custom object called 'company'

When I add 'location' as a property of this object the suggested code looks like:

```
    <meta property="myappname:location:latitude"  content="<?= lat here ?>" /> 
    <meta property="myappname:location:longitude" content="<?= long here ?>" />
```

But the old suggested code looks like this:

```
    <meta property="og:latitude" content="<?= lat here ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:longitude" content="<?= long here ?>"/>
```

And the latter is what apis like foursquare's are expecting.
Is there a reason the tags change for a custom object? Should I use one or both markup types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use both tags. Then pass your URL through the Open Graph debugger at developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to ensure Facebook reads your tags correctly.

Facebook should read your custom namespace tags over the `og:*` tags, and other apps which read this data shouldn't be affected.